# Codesplitting and server-side rendering with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm codesplitting my React+Redux application as described by Dan Abramov [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33044701/352967), and everything appears to work fine. However, I'm also rendering the application on the server. This results in console error documented by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34125207). However, I'm not attempting to clean up old state—I'm loading the state as the server computed it. The problem is the state from the server gets loaded into the global state before the codesplitted modules are loaded.

If I understand Dan properly, the error is just a warning, and everything appears to function correctly, but it's really not a pleasant development workflow to see errors on nearly every page load.

Is there anything I can/should be doing differently with my codesplitting code to alleviate this? It's nearly verbatim to Dan's example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was kind of obvious when it hit me. Just like you send the redux state to the client, you need to tell the client which optional reducers need to be included into the combined reducer on creation.

Based on Dan Abramov's work in the linked answer in my question, I changed `store.asyncReducers` into an array of paths instead of a map of objects. Then I was able to serialize this array and send it to the front-end where it was able to `require` the async reducers that the server-side render used.