# How to get Hot Module Replacement work on Async Reducers?

Tags: webpack, redux

I'm working on a Redux project with dynamic routes and async reducers. I simply inject reducers with Dan's method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968016/how-to-dynamically-load-reducers-for-code-splitting-in-a-redux-application). It becomes quite tricky when I'm trying to write the `module.hot.accept` function for my project. This is what my `configureStore` function is like

```
function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
  let store = createStore(createReducer(), initialState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      thunk
    )
  ))

  store.asyncReducers = {}

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.accept('./routes/root', () =>
        store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.asyncReducers))
      )
    }
  }

  return store
}
```

After I change some code inside of one of the child routes' reducer, I got a warning says `the modules which have changed (and their parents) do not know how to hot reload themselves.` I think the problem is that `injectAsyncRecuder` has not been called since I change the code of the reducer.

How can I make HMR work for async reducers?

=====

Update:

After some research, please let me rephrase my question. Let's say there are 3 levels of routes, A, B and C. A requires B, B requires C. B requires reducer1. C requires reducer2 and reducer3.

```
.
├── Route A                     
│   ├── Route B            
│   |   ├── Reducer 1         
│   |   ├── Route C     
│   |   |   ├── Reducer 2
│   |   |   ├── Reducer 3
```

When Reducer 3 becomes outdated, Route C and Route B will also become outdated. Let's suppose I put `hot.module.accept` in a file which requires Routes A as `hot.module.accept('./routesA', cb)`. I'm wondering how can I check the outdated module stack to find the outdated reducer. In that case, I can put `update` methods in all of the reducers so that they can know hot to inject themselves when becoming outdated.

Comment: did you ever solve this @LASkuma?