# Redux populate default state from Promise

Tags: javascript, redux, default

One of my sub-reducers has a default state that needs to be calculated in a promise.

I could check for an empty state before creating the store, and calculate the  default state, then create the store, but that's very brittle as I'd have to know a lot about state internal structure in a place where it doesn't belong.

Is there an good way to do this?

Comment: I wouldn't delay the creation of the store, because it does not *depend* on the data, it is a fundamental part of your app's mechanism (what happens if your promise is rejected?). I suggest dispatching an INIT_STATE action when the promise resolves.

Comment: [Updated] I'm doing a fully unparametrized operation on the data (imagine a repeatable operation like decompressing a static string), so the promise won't fail and it is more of a "boot state" that's created. The rest of the state contains already known indices into the not-yet-loaded data. So I'll have to handle this on the component level. Perhaps that is cleaner than the original idea though.

Comment: You can create your store after the promise is resolved. and then `ReactDom.render`, or you can have a global 'loading' status to match the Promise resolve status

Comment: #1 sounds like the solution I'm evaluating in the question.

Comment: @OB3 Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: @bebbi Sure, added below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't delay the creation of the store, because it does not depend on the data, it is a fundamental part of your app's mechanism (what happens if your promise is rejected?). I suggest dispatching an `INIT_STATE` action when the promise resolves.

There's also the option of lazy-loading reducers, please look here: [How to dynamically load reducers for code splitting in a Redux application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968016/how-to-dynamically-load-reducers-for-code-splitting-in-a-redux-application)