# Opening a new instance of a React web app in a new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating a reactjs web app, where user has 4 multiple items; lets say A, B, C, and D. App state is managed by Redux.

If user selects any of the above items, he is provided with streaming data for those items and lots of mathematical operators to apply.

> I want to separate memory space of each item for better management of
>   state. A user may also want to monitor lets say all the 4 items at the
>   same time. Therefore I want to provide option for opening each item in
>   its own tab with their own redux state.
>
> Can anyone tell me how to go about it?

The main problem here is not just injecting Reducers but more about how to start a new instance of the App...a react app spawning another react app.

Comment: You probably want to use `injectAsynReducer` of redux. https://gist.github.com/gaearon/0a2213881b5d53973514#file-routes-js-L1

Comment: Thanks, Looks like what I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically load reducers for code splitting in a Redux application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968016/how-to-dynamically-load-reducers-for-code-splitting-in-a-redux-application)

Comment: Have a look on this too. Seems like the same use case and the author of redux has answered it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968016/how-to-dynamically-load-reducers-for-code-splitting-in-a-redux-application

Comment: What I found interesting for my use case is: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/1459

The way it opens index in new tab on click on navigate...that is my use case. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean opening the current app in a new browser (e.g. Chrome) tab, or component based tabs within the same page?

Comment: Opening the current app in a new browser. It has to be done in such a way that the new tab becomes a new instance of the front-end with its own state and bundle. So the user can use the first one for opening further browser tabs for other items if he/she needs so.