# preloadedState when injecting asyncReducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-boilerplate

How is it possible to have both a preloadedState (hydrating from server) and inject reducers dynamically?

In `react-boilerplate` or [How to dynamically load reducers for code splitting in a Redux application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968016/how-to-dynamically-load-reducers-for-code-splitting-in-a-redux-application) there is the concept of reducers which are added dynamically, based on the page/components you are viewing. Extract from `reducers.js`:

```
export default function createReducer(asyncReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    users,
    posts,
    ...asyncReducers
  });
}
```

While this works well when navigating from one page to another (or on a client-side only application); when hydrating data from the server I am encountering this error:

`Unexpected property "comments" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer property names instead: "users", "posts". Unexpected properties will be ignored.`

(where `comments` is the property name of the dynamically injected reducer)

The reason for this error is clear, since the `preloadedState` coming from the server (using React SSR) already contains `comments` and the initial reducer does not since this is added dynamically afterwards. The error disappears if I add `comments` to my `combineReducers`; however that means that at app initialisation I need to include all reducers; which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use dummy reducers in place of dynamically loaded reducers which will be replaced when the real reducers are loaded.

```
{ comments: (state = null) => state }
```

This can also be done automatically, depending on your implementation, as per http://nicolasgallagher.com/redux-modules-and-code-splitting/

```
// Preserve initial state for not-yet-loaded reducers
const combine = (reducers) => {
  const reducerNames = Object.keys(reducers);
  Object.keys(initialState).forEach(item => {
    if (reducerNames.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      reducers[item] = (state = null) => state;
    }
  });
  return combineReducers(reducers);
};
```