# React router route specific create store instead of loading all states on page load in single page application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I want to load only state which are specific to particular route url. Currently I am loading index.js which has below code.

```
import A1 from 'A1Reducer';
import A2 from 'A2Reducer';
import B1 from 'B1Reducer';
import B2 from 'B2Reducer';

export default combineReducers({
  A1: A1,
  A2: A2,
  B1: B1,
  B2: B2
});
```

As per above code I am loading all the states on page load. which is used for different routes

States with name 'A' is used in route  /A and
States with name 'B' is used in route  /B.

So I am storing State B even though it is not used in route A.

I want to create a store based on router route. Please suggest

Comment: This the root reducer right? A, B are something you need to use on a specific page. Am I right?

Comment: @DushanRandika Yes correct

Comment: That means you simply need to get the A data for a specific component and B for another component. You are using redux, So you can use anything in the root reducer and use it where ever you need.

Comment: Got answer from link [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968016/how-to-dynamically-load-reducers-for-code-splitting-in-a-redux-application/33044701#33044701) Thanks